# JMSSerializerBundle transformation on specific type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using the JMSSerializerBundle in a Symfony2 project, combined with Doctrine2.

I've defined a class property as double value, as it represents a product price.

```
/**
 * Price of product
 *
 * @Type("double")
 * @MongoDb\Float */
private $price;
```

It's a requirement to display values with trailing zeros (100.00 instead of 100). I'd like to hook this transformation into the deserialization, as the serializer actually knows he's working with a double value.

Casting all numeric values afterwars won't work, as there's other propertys which must not be affected (like quantity, those must stay integer).

Any ideas/hints on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMSSerializer bundle allows you to define custom serializer/deserializer handler: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers

This allows you to change the way of how a specifc type is being serialized or deserializer.

Comment: I don't think primitive types can have handlers, only objects.

Comment: You can use a handler with a type that uses a primitive type.